# How can you make a PDE solution stabilize over time?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, linear-pde

Suppose I have a simple linear first order PDE of the form:
$$au_x+bu_y=0$$
I want to create a PDE in 3 variables, $x,y,t$ (so the function is now $u(x,y,t)$) such that given an initial condition $u(x,y,t)=u_0(x,y)$ (depending on just the first two variables):

1. If $u_0$ satisfies the original PDE, then the solution to the new PDE is equal to $u_0$ at all times.
2. Generally, as $t\rightarrow \infty$, the solution to the new PDE converges to a function of just two variables $u(x,y)$ which satisfies the original PDE. (converges in what topology? Naturally I'd prefer the topology to be as strong as possible, but I'm open to anything interesting)

So in a sense, I want my PDE to stabilize over time to a PDE of 'less' variables. For instance, I can create a PDE which satisfies the first condition by writing:
$$u_t=au_x+bu_y$$
But it does not generally satisfy the 2nd condition (I checked). An example which comes to mind is the heat equation, which usually stabilizes over time to a harmonic function. But I want something which fits my specific first order PDE. Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this?

This is the first part of my question. The harder part is - if we can find such a method for the PDE above, can we generalize this method for a system of 2 coupled PDE's of the form:
$$au_x+bv_y=0$$
$$cu_y+dv_x=0$$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but maybe something like $u_t = u(x-ay/b, 0) - u(x,y)$ would work? Haven't actually calculated the solution, so maybe it doesn't work, but I think it does follow your first condition at least. The goal was just to make the characteristic curves more constant with time.

Comment: @AnilCh But this is more of a functional equation right? Also, I'm not sure why the first condition holds - if $au_x+bu_y=0$ then if I try to compute $au_x+bu_y$ for the RHS of the PDE above I get:
$u_t=au_x(x-ay/b,0)-au_x(x,y)-au_y(x-ay/b,0)-bu_y(x,y)$
But this does not exactly cancel to 0 since first and third expressions are not the same, right?
But trying to get the characteristic curves to become constant over time is an interesting idea, I'll think about it. Thanks!

Comment: If $u_0$ satisfies the PDE $au_x + bu_y = 0$ then $u$ is constant through characteristics $u(x,y) = u(x+at, y+bt)$, which makes $u(x-ay/b,0) = u(x,y)$ for $t=-y/b$, so $u_t$ would be zero in the equation and it would be conserved. I agree it's more a functional equation than any other thing.